# Immutability of Java objects in Scala

Tags: java, scala

Why this

```
import java.util.HashMap 
val hm = new HashMap[String, String]()
hm.put("hello", "bye")
hm.get("hello")
// res1: String = bye
```

does not pose any problem even though hm is supossed to be immutable. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using a Java data structure in Scala does not make it any less mutable.

Comment: What makes you think HashMap is immutable?  It most certainly is.

Comment: "even though hm is supossed to be immutable" Do you mean the opposite, mutable?

Comment: I mean that because it is defined as val. I was expecting some kind of warning. I *know* that HashMap is mutable, that is the point.

Comment: You are not modifying hm. You are modifying hm's contents.

Comment: Structures are either mutable or immutable. val and vars have nothing to do with it. You don't need to store the map to use it and modify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing the mutability of the variable `hm` with the mutability of the map held by the variable, which are different. `val hm` means that you cannot assign `hm` to any other HashMap, not that the HashMap cannot be modified (as @nmat and @puhlen have explained).

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.HashMap` is not immutable.  This has nothing to do with it coming from java or scala, but the properties of the class itself. You could use a `scala.collection.mutable.HashMap` and see the same behavior.  Likewise, an immutable HashMap implementation written in java would not be mutable if you used it in scala.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.HashMap`is mutable. The Scala immutable counterpart is [scala.collection.immutable.HashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.html):

```
val myMap = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int, String]()
myMap + ((1,"a"), (2, "b")) //new instance of Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)
println(myMap) //Map()
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are a few answers that do a good job of pointing out that there is a difference between an immutable reference and an immutable object, I feel that they miss the key element to help a Java developer understand what is going on. A `val` declaration in Scala is just like a `const` declaration in Java, nothing more. So when you declare

`val hm = new HashMap[String, String]()`

it is equivalent to the Java declaration of

`const HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();`

In both cases, the new object can be mutated, but the reference to it can't be.

The reality is that people should be using `const` a lot more in Java, but they don't because adding those extra characters takes more effort. The decision to use `val` and `var` in Scala effectively removes the cost for declaring `const` references. Of course, this only really gives you complete immutability when you pair it with the immutable types that are part of the Scala libraries. I have a video in the playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLMXbkbDbVt8-dcRqxgdimPtn0bsP_A6W with the title "Mutability and Aliasing" that shows in a graphical way how you might think about this.